# Property value doesn't get saved in class variable

Tags: matlab, class, oop, fft

I have the below class, which contains functions for computing the fourier transformation of a signal.

The functions work, but if try to call `obj.x_k` after using the `dft` method, the vector is empty.

Does anybody know why?

```
classdef DFT
   properties
      x_in
      len
      x_k
      ix_k
   end
   methods
      % Konstruktor
      function obj = DFT(in_v)
        obj.len = length(in_v);
        obj.x_in = in_v;
        obj.x_k = zeros(1,obj.len);
        obj.ix_k = zeros(1,obj.len);
      end
      %Berechnet diskrete Fourier Transformation eines Signals
      function dft(obj)
        i=sqrt(-1);
        for j=0:obj.len-1
            for l=0:obj.len-1
                obj.x_k(j+1)=obj.x_k(j+1)+(obj.x_in(l+1)*exp((-i)*2*pi*j*l/obj.len));
            end
        end
        for j = 0:obj.len-1
            sprintf('x%d: %f + %fi', j+1,obj.x_k(j+1), obj.x_k(j+1)/1i)
        end
        obj.x_k
      end
      %Berechnet inverse diskrete Fourier Transformation eines Signals
      function inversedft(obj)
        i=sqrt(-1);
        for n=0:obj.len-1
            for k=0:obj.len-1
                obj.ix_k(n+1)=(obj.ix_k(n+1)+(obj.x_in(k+1)*exp(i*2*pi*k*n/obj.len)));
            end
        end
        obj.ix_k = 1/obj.len*obj.ix_k;

        for k = 0:obj.len-1
            sprintf('ix%d: %f + %fi', k+1,obj.ix_k(k+1), obj.ix_k(k+1)/1i)
        end
      end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly, your class functions should return the `obj` object:**

```
function obj = dft( obj )
    % ... same code ...
end
```

Not returning it is the same as having a standalone function  which doesn't return anything - you're not storing the result anywhere!

---

**Then you might want to learn about value and handle classes:**

Your class is currently a *value class*. Please read the comments in the following code for expected behaviour:

```
myDFT = DFT(in_v);   % Create DFT object with some input
% Run the method, but don't assign the result to anything! myDFT is unchanged. 
% Pointless unless you don't expect the object to be updated.
myDFT.dft();         
% Run the method and assign the obj output back to the myDFT object.
% *This is what you should do for a value class*
myDFT = myDFT.dft();
```

If you don't want to have to assign the resulting object back, you can use a *handle class*

```
classdef DFT < handle
    % ... same code ...
end
```

Now every time you access the `myDFT` object, you're referencing the same object in memory, not some valued instance of it as before. Note the difference:

```
myDFT = DFT(in_v);   % Create DFT object with some input
% Run the method, myDFT is updated without assigning back! 
% This is because the same instance is changed in memory.
% *This is what you should do for a handle class*
myDFT.dft();     
% This now isn't something you want to or need to do...    
myDFT = myDFT.dft();
```

---

For more, read the documentation.

- [Comparison of handle and value classes](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html)
- [Which kind of class to use](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/which-kind-of-class-to-use.html)
- [Handle classes](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html)